# To combine two catch clasuses in the same

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code:

```
try {
    //do some
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return DynamicFilterErrorCode.INVALID_VALUE;
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    return DynamicFilterErrorCode.INVALID_VALUE;
} catch (IllegaleArgumentException e) {
    return DynamicFilterErrorCode.INVALID_VALUE;
}
```

Is it possible to combine those 3 catch clauses into  one? They have exactly the same handler code, so I'd like to reuse it.

Comment: From java 7 only it is possible. Till java 6, you may handle by catching common parent exception class. However, it will include all other child of that exception.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From Java 7 it is possible :

```
try {
    //do some
} catch (NumberFormatException | ClassCastException | IllegaleArgumentException e) {
    return DynamicFilterErrorCode.INVALID_VALUE;
}
```